# How to set the ListView height

Tags: android, listview, listadapter, baseadapter

I want to know how to set `ListView`'s height through calculating the item view, someone says in this way.

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

if (listAdapter == null) {
    return;
}

int totalHeight = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
    listItem.measure(0, 0);
    totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
}
```

But what if I put into the `ListView` for a class based on `BaseAdapter`?

Comment: is the data which you want to put it in the listview static ? or dynamic ?

Comment: dynamic！  then i will use the "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();"to update the adapter

Comment: so in case of `dynamic`, are you using specific structure in side your adapter to save the data, something like `hashmap` , `arraylist` or you make your adapter read the data from external source such as `server connection` or `database`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BaseAdapter only implement ListAdapter adapter interface, so there is no reason why your code shouldn't work with BaseAdapter. You can try this:

```
BaseAdapter listAdapter = (BaseAdapter)listView.getAdapter();

if (listAdapter == null) {
    return;
}

int totalHeight = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
    listItem.measure(0, 0);
    totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
}
```